# What's wrong with my login script using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO and the login script is not working?
The main reason is that the `password_verify` won't match the actual password.

```
<?php session_start();

include 'conn.php';

if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0) 
{    
    $user   = $_POST['user'];
    $pass   = $_POST['pass'];
    $option=array('cost'=>12);
    $hash=password_hash($pass,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,$option);
    $secure = password_verify( $pass,$hash);    // $secure=hash('sha512',$pass);
    $query  ="SELECT * FROM signup WHERE Username=:users AND Password=:pass";
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->execute(array(':users' => $user,':pass' => $secure));
    $res=$result->fetchColumn();
    if($res>0)
    {
        // Set username session variable
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        // Jump to secured page
        header('location:index.php');
    }//endif
    else
    {
        header('Location:signin.php');
    } 
} 
?>
```

If I use the `hash("algo',$var)` then the script goes fine but using the standard php 5.5 technology it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

`password_verify` returns a boolean. You're currently matching the supplied `$password` against the hash you just generated, that not useful.

```
':pass' => $secure
```

should be

```
':pass' => $hash
```

You don't need to use `password_verify` here.

Comment: Yeah, the correct way would be to pull the hash for that user and compare $password with the stored hash using password_verify... I'm not totally sure but comparing the strings in SQL may be vulnerable to timing attacks because most comparison operators return false upon the first mismatched byte.

Comment: That's a valid point but then you also need to ensure you always do the comparison, even if the username doesn't match. Timing issues get really complex.